# Decrease the space in UISegmentedControl buttons

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I wish to decrease the spacing among the words. I try to decrease the width of the segmented control by using the following code

```
    for i in 0...2 {
        languageSegmentControl.setWidth(45, forSegmentAt: i)
        languageSegmentControl.setContentOffset(CGSize(width: 0, height: 0), forSegmentAt: i)
        //languageSegmentControl.title
    }
```

But the words get truncated and becomes ...  ..

Anyone knows a way to decreasing horizontal spacing?

Thanks!

Comment: try to apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent property of segment to true.

Comment: @DSDharma tried, doesn't work